# mongodb memory server Wrongfully downloading binaries on CircleCi even tho they are cached

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, circleci

Im using [mongodb memory server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-memory-server).

Locally everything passes, but on circle ci it tries to download the binary even tho it's already there.

By running `node node_modules/mongodb-memory-server/postinstall.js` on CircleCi I see this output:

[image]
However then down the line when I run my tests it tries to download the binary again:

[image]
in addition, the SYSTEM_BINARY env variable is set to the path where the binary is.

### Versions

- NodeJS: v17.6.0
- mongodb-memory-server-*: 8.8.0
- mongoose: 6.4.7
- system: ubuntu 20.04

### Code Example

```
// .circleci.config.yml
version: 2.1

orbs:
  node: circleci/node@5.0.2

jobs:
  main:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:lts-browsers
    steps:
      - checkout
      - node/install-packages:
          pkg-manager: yarn
      - run: echo $SYSTEM_BINARY
      - run: node node_modules/mongodb-memory-server/postinstall.js
      - run: yarn test:api

workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - main

// mock-db-test-util.js
import { MongoMemoryServer } from "mongodb-memory-server"
import mockMongoose from "mongoose"

const mockMongoMemoryServer = MongoMemoryServer.create()

// @ts-ignore
jest.mock("../../src/db", () => ({
  // @ts-ignore
  ...(jest.requireActual("../../src/db").default as any),
  // @ts-ignore
  connect: jest.fn().mockImplementation(async () => {
    const mongo = await mockMongoMemoryServer
    const uri = mongo.getUri()
    await mockMongoose.connect(uri)
  }),
}))
```